# flock() keeps waiting for lock to be released

Tags: php, apache, locking

so i want to lock a file so i can see that a php process is already running. The example code looks as follows:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("test.txt","w+");

if (flock($file,LOCK_EX))
  {
    fwrite($file,"Write something");
    sleep(10);
    flock($file,LOCK_UN);
  }
 else
  {
     echo "Error locking file!";
  }

 fclose($file);
?>
```

But the problem is that when i executed this file, and execute the file again the second waits for the first one to be done with the lock. So then both are successfully executed. But only the first one has to be executed successfully. Anyknow know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want flock to be blocking? You just want the first process to obtain the lock and the second one to fail?

To do that, you can use the `LOCK_NB` flag to stop the `flock` call from blocking:

```
$file = fopen("test.txt","r+");

if (flock($file,LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB))
  {
    fwrite($file,"Write something");
    sleep(10);
    flock($file,LOCK_UN);
  }
 else
  {
     echo "Error locking file!";
  }

 fclose($file);
```

More info is available on the PHP flock doc page - http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Comment: I want the first process the obtain to lock and the second one to fail indeed. The problem is when i test this code, the 2 browser pages still both return success(if i place a echo in the if statement).

Comment: I tested at the command line, and it works for me; do you still have the `sleep` there when testing in the browser? Are you on Windows, that doesn't support the `LOCK_NB` flag.

Comment: Yes i have the sleep and yes i'm on windows but the server runs on ubuntu.

Comment: Humm, I have now tested this with Apache too and it is working for me - in one browser window I get the message "Error locking file!" and in the other i get a message which I added after the fwrite. Does your apache user have permissions to create the test.txt file? Perhaps there is another issue here?

Comment: I have replaced the w+ to x, and then the first time it is working for me. The other problem is that x can only create the file when it does not exist, so it gives a error message when it exist

Comment: Try using the `r+` flags

Comment: Perhaps try a Semaphore or a Mutex if this still does not work on your system

Comment: still does not work, gettig the same result. The second web page just waits for the first one to be done

Comment: Do u have any idea where the problem can be?

Comment: Can you test again, but using curl from the command line? If you test outside of the browser you might be better able to see if it is working. Like I said before, it works for me - I am also using Ubuntu - works at the command line (running like this: `php -q test.php` and also with curl

Comment: a curl to the file that has to be locked?

Comment: No, I mean curl the test php script - like `curl http://myserver/test.php` and then do the same in another terminal window - the second one should show "Error locking file" while the other one takes 10 seconds

Comment: On ubuntu the curls works perfectly fine. Only in the browsers it will not work... Verry weird

Comment: After searching i found that the browser sees it as one process when you make 2 windows in the same browser. In different browsers(on different desktop's) or in the terminal this code works fine. Ty!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a second file called e.g. "test.txt.updated" and maintain the state there -- i.e., whether "test.txt" was already updated or not. Something like the following. NOTE, I've opened "text.txt" in append-mode to see whether two concurrent runs really wrote only once to the file.

```
<?php

if (! ($f = fopen("text.txt", "a")) )
    print("Cannot write text.txt\n");
elseif (! flock($f, LOCK_EX))
    print("Error locking text.txt\n");
else {
    print("Locked text.txt\n");
    if (file_exists("text.txt.updated"))
        print("text.txt already updated\n");
    else {
        print("Updating text.txt and creating text.txt.updated\n");
        fwrite($f, "Write something\n");
        if ($stamp = fopen("text.txt.updated", "w"))
            fwrite($stamp, "whatever\n");
        else
            print("Oooooops, can't create the updated state file\n");
        sleep(10);
    }
    flock($f, LOCK_UN);
}

?>
```